# Arrangement of sequence of 'n' numbers

Tags: algorithm, math, permutation

In how many ways can you arrange a sequence of 'n' (1 to n) numbers such that no number occurs at the index represent by its value?

For eg

```
1 can not be at first position
2 can not be at second position
.
.
n can not be at nth position
```

Please give a general solution. Also solve it for n=6.
Its not a homework.

Comment: If it walks like a duck, and talks like a duck... are you *sure* it's not homework?

Comment: The question of how to generate derangements programmatically has been [dealt with previously here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8369941/487781).  The formula to count them is strictly speaking a math topic (and see my answer linking to such a question at MathSE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let P(n) be the number of such arrangements for `n` numbers.

```
For 123456....n
Cases are of the form

2*****
3*****
4*****
5*****
.
.
n*****

Now 1 can be anywhere at the rest (n-1) positions.
If 1 is put at the position of the number replacing it...

21****
3*1***
4**1**
.
.
n****1

then first and the replaced numbers are fixed.
Then total cases = (n-1) * P(n-2)

Else if
1 is also restricted not to be at a particular position (positions in above cases)
Then total cases = (n-1) * P(n-1)
```

So

P(n) = (P(n-1) + P(n-2)) * (n-1)

with P(1) = 0

and P(2) = 1

Answer (score 2):

You want fixed point free permutations, also known as [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). The formula for their number is slightly more complicated than for the number of permutations that may have fixed points.

Comment: Very slightly, the nearest integer to n!/e.  The Wikipedia article doesn't explain this clearly, though it notes the fraction of derangements converges to 1/e and gives `floor((n!/e) + (1/2))` as an exact expression.

Answer (score 1):

The number of derangements (fixed point free permutations) of `n` things is `round(n!/e)` where `e` is the base of natural logarithms.  Here `round` means nearest integer function.  This is described in [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), but in a manner that could stand clarification.

For `n = 6` one easily calculates there are `round(264.87...) = 265` derangements.

In effect you've asked [a frequently covered question from MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14666/3111).