# Random valid permutations of an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, permutation

Suppose that we are given arrays `A` and `B` of positive integers. `A` and `B` contain the same integers (the same number of times), so they are naturally the same length.

Consider permutations of two arrays `U` and `V` to be *valid* if `U[i] != V[i]` for `i = 0, 1, ..., len(U) - 1`.

We want to find a valid pair of permutations for `A` and `B`. However, we want our algorithm to be such that all pairs of valid permutations are equally likely to be returned.

---

I've been working on this problem today and cannot seem to come up with a sleek solution. Here is my best solution thus far:

```
import random

def random_valid_permutation(values):
    A = values[:]
    B = values[:]

    while not is_valid_permutation(A, B):
        random.shuffle(A)
        random.shuffle(B)

    return A, B

def is_valid_permutation(A, B):
    return all([A[i] != B[i] for i in range(len(A))])
```

Unfortunately, since this method involves a random shuffle of each array, it could in theory take infinite time to produce a valid output. I have come up with a couple of alternatives that *do* run in finite (and reasonable) time, but their implementation is much longer.

Does anyone know of a sleek way to solve this problem?

Comment: These are known as [derangements] and this was actually [asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200220/generate-a-random-derangement-of-a-list) here on Stack Overflow. [This particular answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25238398/1473772) may be the most "sleek" answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

First note that every permutation, A, has the same number of derangements B as any other permutation A. Thus it is enough to generate a single A and then generate random B until you get a match. The probability that a permutation, B, is a derangement of A is known to be (approximately) 1/e (a little better than 1 out of 3) in a way that is essentially independent of the number of items. There is over a 99% probability that you will find a valid B with less than a dozen trials. Unless your list of values is large, fishing using the built-in `random.shuffle` might be quicker than rolling your own with the overhead of checking with each new placement of an item if it has led to a clash. The following is almost instantaneous with a thousand elements and still only takes about a second or so with a million elements:

```
import random

def random_valid_permutation(values):
    A = values[:]
    B = values[:]
    random.shuffle(A)
    random.shuffle(B)

    while not is_valid_permutation(A, B):
        random.shuffle(B)

    return A, B

def is_valid_permutation(A, B):
    return all(A[i] != B[i] for i in range(len(A)))
```

As an optimization -- I removed `[` and `]` form the definition of `is_valid_permutation()` since `all` can work directly on generator expressions. There is no reason to create the whole list in memory since any clash will typically detected long before the end of the list.