# Generate a random index from list which does not include one specific index

Tags: python, random

I have a list of integers: `l = [1,2,3,4]`

For each element in this list I need to randomly select a *different* element and perform some operation on it:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
   idx = # a random index which is NOT equal to i
   # do something with the element at idx
```

I'm still pretty new to Python and can't determine if there is a way to do this without resorting to a loop where I generate a random index and only stop the loop if the random number is not equal to `i`. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will find help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200220/generate-a-random-derangement-of-a-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this: Generate a random number between<sup>1</sup> `0` and `N - 1` (`N` being the length of the list in this case), then add one to that number if it is equal to or greater than `i`.

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    idx = random.randrange(len(l) - 1)
    idx = idx + 1 if idx >= i else idx
    # do stuff with idx
```

This way, all the numbers rolled above `i` are shifted "one up":

```
       0      i          N
before *****************
after  ******* **********
```

---

Or, in a single line, you could generate a number between<sup>1</sup> `i + 1` and `N + i` and take that number modulo `N`, effectively wrapping it around after the end of the list:

```
    idx = random.randrange(i + 1, len(l) + i) % len(l)

       0      i          N
before         *****************
after  ******* **********
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> Here meaning including the lower bound and excluding the upper bound, using `randrange`

Comment: Yes, that you @tobias_k that is exactly what I was looking for. I'll accept it as soon as SO will allow me.

Comment: why not just
 idx = idx + 1 if idx == i else idx?

Comment: @Alexey You have to shift all the "higher" `idx`, otherwise the chance for `i+1` is twice as high, and `len(l)-1` will never be rolled. See my edit. You _could_ do `idx = len(l)-1 if idx == i else idx`, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5]
import random as rd 
def remove_index(list,index):
    res=list[:]
    res.pop(index)
    return res

for i in range(len(l)):
    print rd.choice(remove_index(l,i))
```

Comment: You want to make a _full copy_ of the list on each iteration? What if my list was millions of items long?

Comment: I guess it's kinda inefficient. I'm actually new to python so i took it as an exercise in python syntax.

Comment: Yep, look at tobias_k's solution. It requires so additional memory and only a single extra comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Short `numpy` approach:

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array([1,2,3,4])
for i in range(len(l)):
    idx = random.choice(np.where(l != l[i])[0])
    # do stuff with idx
    print(i, idx)
```

The output (showing index difference):

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 1
```

Comment: This does not work properly if the list contained duplicate elements (and assuming that an equal element could be picked, as long as it's at a different position)

Comment: @tobias_k, nobody mentioned about *duplicate elements*, the OP wrote about different indices. Why are writing about *duplicate elements*?

Comment: Nobody mentioned duplicate elements, but that does not mean that they are not a concern. OP asked for a random index other than the current index, whereas your code produces a random index other than any index that has the current element or a duplicate thereof.

Comment: @tobias_k, if the OP confirmed that

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
size = len(l)
idxl = [random.choice([j for j in range(size) if j != i]) for i in range(size)]

for idx in idxl:
    # do something with the element at idx
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

l = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for x in l:
    new_el = random.choice(l)
    while new_el == x:
        new_el = random.choice(l)
    print new_el
```

Comment: That is _exactly_ what I described in my question @Alexey. I'm looking for something _other_ than that. I was hoping NumPy, etc. would be able to do this.