# Shuffling php array without same value before or after

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

To shuffle an array in php is easy but my problem is when i try to shuffle it without getting the same result before of after that key.

Example:

```
Array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3, 3 => 3 )
```

I must have a result without 3 coming together.

Example of some array i want:

```
Array ( 0 => 2, 1 => 3, 2 => 1, 3 => 3 )
```

I've tryed to check each item of the array, if that happens i shuffle it again, and check another time. But that seems to be waste both on time and process.

**EDIT:**
Here is the code i use:

```
do
{
    $not_valid=false;
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arr_times)-1;$i++){
        if($arr_times[$i]==$arr_times[$i+1])
            $not_valid=true;
    }
    if($not_valid)
        shuffle($arr_times);
}while ($not_valid);
```

Comment: Is there any possible way of doing it without having to read the whole array again each time i shuffle it?

Comment: actually I wouldn't amaze that php had `shuffle_without_same_value_before` function, as it has already some strange one. But in this case - no, it doesn't. And you have to do that manually.

Comment: Do you want an array that doesn't have any values with their old index, or an array that doesn't have any values equal to their index?

Comment: @arxanas i need an array without the same value before or after, not the key.

Answer (score 0):

Even though php has really a lot of strange functions - it doesn't have any for described situation.

So you have to do that manually.

PS: also it would be a good idea to check if it's even possible to shuffle input array in an expected way so you wouldn't get into an infinite loop.

Comment: Do u have any good ideas for the code that i put on my question on the "edit" area?

Answer (score 0):

From [Shuffle list, ensuring that no item remains in same position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279895/shuffle-list-ensuring-that-no-item-remains-in-same-position)

```
<?php
$foo = array(
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
);

for ($i = 0, $c = sizeof($foo); $i < $c - 1; $i++) {
    $new_i = rand($i + 1, $c - 1);
    list($foo[$i], $foo[$new_i]) = array($foo[$new_i], $foo[$i]);
}

var_export($foo); // Derangement
```

Comment: So your solution is to use this randomization after the first shuffle if the array has the same items?

Comment: My solution is to use this for loop to randomize.

Comment: @arxanas: current question has nothing to do with "Shuffle list, ensuring that no item remains in same position". Your code **doesn't guarantee** there will be no duplicates in a row

Comment: @zerkms But does it not guarantee that no items will remain in the same position?

Comment: @arxanas: op didn't ask about not staying in the same position, did he?