# shuffle a PHP array so that no value remains in it's original position

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

I've been searching for this for a while but none of the solutions I've found match what I'm looking for.

Say I have an array of names:

```
$names = array('zack', 'tom', 'brad', 'tim');
```

I'd like to randomise those names but none can end up in the same position as it started in.

the shuffle() function doesn't seem do this.

I have tried the following which is probably not the best way to do it but for some reason this didn't work?:

```
$names = array('zack', 'tom', 'brad', 'tim');
$names2 = array('zack', 'tom', 'brad', 'tim');

do {
  shuffle($names2);
} while($names === $names2);
```

I also need to keep the original array in the original order so shuffling the array and then shifting by one isn't an option.

How do i achieve a shuffle with no value remaining in it's original position?

Comment: "I'd like to randomise those names but none can end up in the same position as it started in." -> In this case the result is not random, it's restricted by one rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a brute force method I came up with..

It runs `shuffle` until the two arrays are different.
**Note that this is not ideal and can take a long time for bigger arrays:)**

http://codepad.viper-7.com/c8EFOc

```
$names = array('zack', 'tom', 'brad', 'tim');
$names2 = $names;

while(count(array_intersect_assoc($names, $names2))) {
    shuffle($names2);
    var_dump('Array1:', $names);
    echo '<br/>';
    var_dump('Array2:', $names2);
    echo '<br/>';
}

echo 'Done!';
```

Edit: Also have a look at [Shuffling php array without same value before or after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240388/shuffling-php-array-without-same-value-before-or-after?rq=1) and [Shuffle list, ensuring that no item remains in same position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279895/shuffle-list-ensuring-that-no-item-remains-in-same-position)