# pandas sample based on category for each row

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe

```
   rid category
0   0       c2
1   1       c3
2   2       c2
3   3       c3
4   4       c2
5   5       c2
6   6       c1
7   7       c3
8   8       c1
9   9       c3
```

I want to add 2 columns pid and nid, such that for each row pid contains a random id (other than rid) that belongs to the same category as rid and nid contains a random id that belongs to a different category as rid,

an example dataframe would be:

```
   rid category pid nid
0   0       c2   2   1
1   1       c3   7   4
2   2       c2   0   1
3   3       c3   1   5
4   4       c2   5   7
5   5       c2   4   6  
6   6       c1   8   5
7   7       c3   9   8
8   8       c1   6   2
9   9       c3   1   2
```

Note that pid should not be the same as rid. Right now, I am just brute forcing it by iterating through the rows and sampling each time, which seems very inefficient.

Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT 1:** For simplicity let us assume that each category is represented at least twice, so that at least one id can be found that is not rid but has the same category.

**EDIT 2:** For further simplicity let us assume that in a large dataframe the probability of ending up with the same id as rid is zero. If that is the case I believe the solution should be easier. I would **prefer not to make this assumption** though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pid column use [`Sattolo's algorithm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Sattolo.27s_algorithm) and for `nid` get all possible values with difference all volues of column with values of group with [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) and `set` difference:

```
from random import randrange

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279895
def sattoloCycle(items):
    items = list(items)
    i = len(items)
    while i > 1:
        i = i - 1
        j = randrange(i)  # 0 <= j <= i-1
        items[j], items[i] = items[i], items[j]
    return items

def outsideGroupRand(x):
    return np.random.choice(list(set(df['rid']).difference(x)), 
                            size=len(x),
                            replace=False)


df['pid1'] = df.groupby('category')['rid'].transform(sattoloCycle)
df['nid1'] =  df.groupby('category')['rid'].transform(outsideGroupRand)
print (df)
   rid category  pid  nid  pid1  nid1
0    0       c2    2    1     4     6
1    1       c3    7    4     7     4
2    2       c2    0    1     5     3
3    3       c3    1    5     1     0
4    4       c2    5    7     2     9
5    5       c2    4    6     0     8
6    6       c1    8    5     8     3
7    7       c3    9    8     9     5
8    8       c1    6    2     6     5
9    9       c3    1    2     3     6
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

## generate dummy data
raw = {
    "rid": range(10),
    "cat": np.random.choice("c1,c2,c3".split(","), 10)   
}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw)


def get_random_ids(x):
    pids,nids = [],[]    

    sh = x.copy()
    for _ in x:
        ## do circular shift choose random value except cur_val
        cur_value = sh.iloc[0]
        sh = sh.shift(-1)
        sh[-1:] = cur_value
        pids.append(np.random.choice(sh[:-1]))

    ## randomly choose from values from other cat
    nids = np.random.choice(df[df["cat"]!=x.name]["rid"], len(x))

    return pd.DataFrame({"pid": pids, "nid": nids}, index=x.index)

new_ids = df.groupby("cat")["rid"].apply(lambda x:get_random_ids(x))
df.join(new_ids).sort_values("cat")
```

**output**

```
    rid cat pid nid
5   5   c1  8.0 9
8   8   c1  5.0 6
0   0   c2  6.0 1
2   2   c2  0.0 8
3   3   c2  0.0 9
6   6   c2  2.0 4
7   7   c2  3.0 1
1   1   c3  9.0 5
4   4   c3  9.0 0
9   9   c3  4.0 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with defining a function computing *pid*:

```
def getPid(elem, grp):
    return grp[grp != elem].sample().values[0]
```

Parameters:

- *eleme* - the current *rid* from group,
- *grp* - the whole group of *rid* values.

The idea is to:

- select "other" elements from the current group (for some *category*),
- call *sample*,
- return the only returned value from a *Series* returned by *sample*.

Then define second function, generating both new ids:

```
def getIds(grp):
    pids = grp.rid.apply(getPid, grp=grp.rid)
    rowNo = grp.rid.size
    currGrp = grp.name
    nids = df.query('category != @currGrp').rid\
        .sample(rowNo, replace=True)
    return pd.DataFrame({'pid': pids, 'nid': nids.values}, index=grp.index)
```

Note that:

- all *nid* values for the current group can be computed with
  a **single** call to *sample*,
- from a *Series* of *rid*s for "other categories.

But *pid* values must be computed **separately**, applying *getPid* to each
element (*rid*) of the current group.

The reason is that each time a different element should be eliminated
from the current group, before *sample* is called.

And to get the result, run a **single** instruction:

```
pd.concat([df, df.groupby('category').apply(getIds)], axis=1)
```