# Random rearrangement of a vector in R

Tags: r

For example, I have a vector like below,

```
a = c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I want to rearrange it into the vector that no element are in its original position, that is

```
a' = c(2,3,1,5,4) # this one is correct

a'' = c(1,3,4,5,2) # this one is wrong
```

how can I do this

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279895/shuffle-list-ensuring-that-no-item-remains-in-same-position